# Imported image (then stored in object) does not render (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, import, react-hooks

I wanted to import images, store them in an array of objects, and loop through them with a map-function. I get no error in VSCode, but the images do not render. When I inspect, i do see that the image is not read like it should be. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

imageimport:

```
import folder from './assets/icons/folder.svg';
import about from './assets/icons/about.svg';
import code from './assets/icons/code.svg';
import contact from './assets/icons/contact.svg';
import photos from './assets/icons/photos.svg';

export { folder }; 
export { about }; 
export { code }; 
export { contact }; 
export { photos };
```

import into component:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "./home.scss";
import { folder, about, code, contact, photos } from '../imageimport';

function Home() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    {
      icon: {folder},
      title: "New Folder",
    },
    {
      icon: {photos},
      title: "Pics",
    },
    {
      icon: {code},
      title: "Web Dev",
    },
    {
      icon: {contact},
      title: "Contact",
    },
    {
      icon: {about},
      title: "About",
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {buttons.map((item, i) => (
        <div className="home_items">
            <img className="home_items-icon" src={item.icon}></img>
            {item.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Inspection with DevTools

```
<div class="desktop_items"><img class="desktop_items-icon" src="[object Object]">New Folder</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change from `icon: {folder}` to `icon: folder`